# URL Rewrite Config when Installing Phabricator on cPanel/WHM

Tags: mod-rewrite, cpanel, phabricator

I'm trying to install Phabricator on a cPanel/WHM server. According to this page:

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/#next-steps

I need to add some URL rewriting configuration to httpd.conf, but that's not really possible with cPanel, and the error is:

```
Request parameter '__path__' is not set. Your rewrite rules are not configured correctly.
```

I tried copying the rewrite rules to Phabricator's web root, and this should work, but it doesn't, and gives a 500 error, without any error log entries.

Tried changing this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /index.php?__path__=$1  [B,L,QSA]
```

by removing the first slash (in case it didn't recognize this as the root directory), but it didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a guide on installing Phabricator with cPanel/WHM (I wasn't able to find one)?

Note: I have root and WHM access to the server, but would like to avoid making changes that would require these permissions, if possible.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend installing Phabricator on anything other than a "normal computer". You're likely to run into many such problems, and the upstream will not be able to provide you any support.

Comment: You are right based on what I've seen so far, but setting up a new VM dedicated to Phabricator would actually make it more expensive than competing products, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Not sure if the pain it takes to set up is worth it, but if I figure everything out maybe someone will benefit from this knowledge.

Comment: You can get a free micro instance on AWS for a year if you're a new customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is really not the biggest problem when installing Phabricator on cPanel/WHM, the solution to it is a vHost-specific include, supported by cPanel/WHM. Here is a simple guide:

http://tecadmin.net/add-custom-settings-in-whm-cpanel-apache-virtualhost/

Some more information (although potentially more confusing) can be found here:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Modify+Virtualhost+Containers+With+Include+Files